# How to import a vector icon from directory in React Native?

Tags: react-native, vector-icons

I would like to know how to import vector icon I've created or from directory in pc by using react native?

Comment: what is the format of icon ? PNG ?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've already written to try and solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're trying to use custom `font` icons. I've built a library to make it easy.

https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-custom-icon

### Usage:

```
import MyIcon from "react-native-custom-icon";
import IcomoonConfig from "./assets/icomoon/selection.json";

<MyIcon name="fireworks" color="red" size={50} config={IcomoonConfig} />
```

You need to install react-native-vector-icons. It's a must dependency. You can put your svg icons to `https://icomoon.io/` and get your .ttf font icons from there. It comes with `selection.json` and `icomoon.ttf` files. All you need to do is; put these files on your project and look at the above usage example.

If you cannot make it, I wrote a [Step By Step Guide](https://freakycoder.com/react-native-library-react-native-custom-icon-1ec0b734d691)